# Getting app domain error in facebook app basics settings after sandbox mode disabled.

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, sandbox

I'm working on getting the fb.logInStatus to work and I pulled up a question someone previously answered about it that suggested that sandbox mode be disabled. I did that and then I got an error on the facbook app settings page that says Error

```
App Domains: `http://localhost:80/controllers/index.php` should not contain protocol information.
```

Why is it suddenly rejecting the 'http' in disabled sandbox mode? what does that mean?

Comment: _“should not contain protocol information”_ – is that message not very very clear all in itself already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're filling in the 'app domains' field, it should contain a domain which matches your 'website' or 'app on facebook' url - e.g. it should be 'something.com', without protocol identifier, and no path. Just the domain.

This won't work with localhost except for testing purposes in sandbox mode. (how would it work for any other user if the code is on your machine?)